# Reduction from partition to multiprocessor scheduling

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

I am kind of unsure about a reduction between two problems.
Here are the two problems:

**PARTITION:**
Instance: A finite set of n positive integers $S= \{a_1,a_2,...a_n\}$.
Question: Can the set $S$ be partitioned into two subsets $S_1$,$S_2$, s.t. the sum of the numbers in $S_1$ equals the sum of the numbers in $S_2$?

**MULTIPROCESSOR SCHEDULING:**
Instance: A set $J$ of $k$ jobs where job $j_i$ has length $l_i$, and $m$ processors.
Question: Can we schedule all jobs in $J$ on $m$ processors s.t.:
**(a)** on each processor the next job in the sequence is started immediately after the preceding job is finished and **(b)** the total time to execute all jobs on each processor takes the minimum possible time $T_{min}=\big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^k l_i\big)/m$

I am a little bit unsure about my try to reduce Partition to multiprocessor scheduling. My attempt is posted as an answer.

Comment: I have moved your attempt to an answer, because that fits the site format better. I will comment there about correctness/improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is the answer that the OP wanted to have checked.)

Let $S=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ be an arbitrary instance of Partition. In our reduction we set $J=S$. if $\sum\limits_{a \in S} a$ is even, we set $m=2$. Note: If the sum of elements in $S$ is odd, there cannot be a Partitioning. Further, we set the length $l_i$ of job $j_i$ to the value of $a_i$.

So this is my reduction. But I am very unsure if this is just too easy? Note that I do not have to provide the correctness proof but just the reduction. Is this somehow a right reduction? I am very unsure if I have to distinguish between the two cases where the sum of elements of $S$ is odd or even. What if the sum is odd?

Can someone give me some hints on that?

Comment: The reduction is basically correct. You do not need to make a case distinction for odd sum: In that case the reduction will give an instance that cannot be scheduled, just as needed.